# How can I connect Grails 4 with SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, grails

I followed the normal procedure for connecting with database as it's done in SPRING BOOT but none of my method seems to work. Also I used the below procedure for connects SQL Server and I added SQL Server driver in lib directory but there is no any result. Is there any one who can help me with this please?

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    username: cctz
    password: 'cctz*2020'
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2019Dialect

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<192.168.200.136>\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=deptech_db;user=cctz;password=cctz*2020;

    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.200.136:1433;DatabaseName=deptech_db
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.200.136:1433;DatabaseName=deptech_db
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: Are the `<` and `>` characters really in your connection URL, or is that a copy-paste typo?

Comment: Also, if it's an SQL Server Express instance it may not be listening on the port you expect. If the TCPIP protocol is even enabled Express usually listens on a localhost port only, i.e.: 127.0.0.1. Try opening SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager on the machine hosting the instance and check the Server Protocols > TCPIP Protocol settings to see that they're enabled and listening on the IP address(es) and port(s) that you expect.

Comment: any exceptions in the log?